# Javascript - HTMLCollection to string using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Hi I am trying to update a div with some html from another div.

```
var results = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
$("resultsDiv").update(results);
```

I then get this: [object HTMLCollection]
How do I convert it to a string so it is shown as html in my div ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just copy and paste the innerhtml.

```
var data = div1.innerHTML;
div2.innerHTML=data;
```

otherwise you have to deal with all the altering of DOM nodes,